# How to scroll to bottom of an element in NgFor while adding element?

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>

  <div #commentDetailWrapper style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid; width: 100px; overflow-y:scroll ">

<div *ngFor="let axe of axes"><button>Filler</button></div>

  </div>
  <button (click)='add()'>Add More</button>


  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  @ViewChild('commentDetailWrapper', { static: false }) commentDetailWrapper;

  axes = Array(10);

  add() {
    this.axes.push(Array(1));
    const el: HTMLDivElement = this.commentDetailWrapper.nativeElement;
    el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const el: HTMLDivElement = this.commentDetailWrapper.nativeElement;
    el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
  }

}
```

This works on Default it scrolls to the last element how do I scroll to bottom when I add a new element by clicking on the `add More` button

Here is the problem Working Demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-offfw4)

**Desired Result: scroll to bottom on clicking add more button**

Comment: Take a look at EventEmitters or BehaviorSubjects.

Comment: @A.Sharma when should I emit an event and when should I catch it ?

Comment: emit the event whenever you add to the array..at the end of the add function

Comment: @A.Sharma I don't think that will work

Comment: Have you tried? Emitting/Subscribing events is a pretty core concept to RxJS/Angular. Emit when you add to the array and the subscription function should handle the logic to scroll. You may need to combine it with NgZone, but it should definitely work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the scroll after a timeout solves the problem. Since the view is not updated when you try to scroll.

**Solution 1:**
using `AfterViewChecked` hook,

```
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {
added:boolean;
 ...
   add() {
    this.axes.push(Array(1));
    this.added = true;
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
   // run only when new axe is added
   if(this.added) {
    const el: HTMLDivElement = this.commentDetailWrapper.nativeElement;
    el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
    this.added = false;
   }
  }
...
}
```

**Solution 2:**
using `setTimeout`,

```
...
add() {
   this.axes.push(Array(1));
   const el: HTMLDivElement = this.commentDetailWrapper.nativeElement;
   setTimeout(() => {
     el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
   });
}
...
```

**Solution 1a:**
Separating the component and make the input data immutable. Used `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` for the implementation

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zjf4a

Comment: Both of these should work.  OP may be interested in this: https://www.quora.com/Does-JavaScript-in-the-browser-have-the-equivalent-of-process-nextTick-or-setImmediate-in-node-js-or-do-we-just-have-setTimeout

Comment: `ngAfterViewChecked` won't work for me since it will trigger on any dom change e.x it will scroll to bottom on window resize too, `setTimeout` works But I will wait if there is a better way to do without setTimeout

Comment: @NathanielJohnson didn't get you

Comment: @dota2pro setTimeout is going to be the answer then.  The browser needs to handle the DOM operation as it's not synchronous.  setTimeout with no value is a trick to push an operation on the async stack after all the stuff on it is done.  The article talks about other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Strictly opinion here but I think you should make the internal element its own component with its own events.  By going down to DOM elements you are making your code difficult to maintain and not really creating an angular app.  Just opinion :)

Comment: @NathanielJohnson do you happen to know any library or directive for scroll to bottom ?

Comment: @dota2pro adding a condition would solve the issue. Added one more solution

Comment: `setTimeout` seems patchy. `ngAfterViewChecked` seems messy.

Comment: @ajaiJothi it doesnt work if you remove the `AfterViewChecked` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7aywh?file=src/app/axes/axes.component.ts

Comment: @dota2pro why you are removing AfterViewChecked? you still need that. Solution 3 just separates the concern